# If the prefix milli- means 1E-3, why does "million" mean 1E6?

Tags: etymology

Is there a reason *million* diverges from the metric system convention?

Comment: The metric system was devised well ***after*** the number *million* was named. In Latin, *mille* meant a thousand. In French, *mille* meant a thousand, *million* meant a thousand thousand (10^6), and *milliard* meant a thousand thousand thousand (10^9). The metric system prefix *milli-* comes from the Latin word.

Comment: @PeterShor, That's awesome.  Please post your answer as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2):

*sigh*, [another answer in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277302/if-the-prefix-milli-means-1e-3-why-does-million-mean-1e6?noredirect=1#comment613196_277302) that would have been perfectly suited down here.

> The metric system was devised well after the number million was named. In Latin, mille meant a thousand. In French, mille meant a thousand, million meant a thousand thousand (10^6), and milliard meant a thousand thousand thousand (10^9). The metric system prefix milli- comes from the Latin word.